# How to tweet with Twitterizer by using C#

Tags: c#, twitterizer, tweets

i downloaded latest Twitterizer  . added these references.

```
using Twitterizer.Core;
using Twitterizer.Data;
using Twitterizer.Entities;
using Twitterizer.Streaming;
```

now what do i need to do ? i searched internet but examples are old and probably not supported by twitter. can anbody explain me step by step ?

i just want to tweet via my account.

*Edit: Problem solved by using TweetSharp. i suggest you to use TweetSharp instead of Twitterizer .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include `using Twitterizer;` and not the others.

I have an example application posted on the downloads page: http://www.twitterizer.net/downloads/ It's an ASP.NET application, but the code and usage will be the same for desktop applications.

You can find access to methods by invoking methods on the main classes, such as:
TwitterUser
TwitterStatus (for tweets)
TwitterTimeline

You may also want to check out the code samples posted: http://www.twitterizer.net/category/code-sample/

Comment: i already checked both link. very poor documentation and guides. also solved tweeting problem with tweetsharp. it is alot better than Twitterizer.

Comment: Agree. Twitterizer is overly complex for simple tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you see the code examples on this page:
http://www.twitterizer.net/

Also see the docs page:
http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/

The API seems a little confusing to me, never heard of this library.

Why not use Linq to Twitter : http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Its used by a lot of people.